# Duda con metodo findUser de mi aplicacion

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una aplicación y tengo una duda...Explico:

El registro de usuarios se hace directamente en la clase (Platform). Para registrarse, el usuario debe indicar un nombre de usuario, una contraseña y su nombre completo (Nombre y Apellidos).

Hay que tener en cuenta que:

 Un usuario lo identifico por su nombre de usuario (username). No puede haber usuarios con nombres de usuario repetidos.

 Dos usuarios se consideran iguales si su usuario, contraseña y nombre completo son iguales.

Como resultado de la creación, se generará un nuevo objeto del tipo User. Este objeto permitirá interactuar con la clase platform. En caso de que un usuario con el mismo nombre ya exista, no se creará el nuevo usuario, y se devolverá un null para indicar el error.

Para verificar si un usuario existe o no, implemento el método findUser, que me permita buscar un usuario registrado a partir de su nombre de usuario. En caso de que no exista, este método devolverá un valor null.

Para probar el correcto funcionamiento del código desarrollado, tengo la clase de pruebas: PR1_Ex2_1_Test

Las clases las tengo definidas asi:

La clase Platform que es donde hago todos los métodos

```
            package edu.uoc.dpoo;
            import java.util.ArrayList; 
            import java.util.List;

            /**
             *
             * @author Guillermo Rodriguez Barcelo
              */
            public class Platform {

private List<Competition> competitions;
private List<User> users;

public Platform(){

    competitions = new ArrayList<Competition>();
    users = new ArrayList<User>();

}
public User registerUser(String username ,String password,String fullname){

    User p = findUser(username);
    if (p == null) {
        p =  new User(username, password,fullname);
        users.add(p);
    }
    else {
        p.getUserName();
    }

    return (User) p;
}



public User findUser (String username) {


           User user = null;

    for (User p : users) {
        if (username.equals(p.getUserName())) {
            user = p;
            break;
        }
    }

    return user;
}


public User login(String username,String password){
    return null;
}
public Integer getNumUsers(){
    Integer  size=users.size();

    return size  ;
}
public Integer getNumCompetitions(){
    return null;
}
public Message sendMessage(User from,String to,String subject,String message){
    return null;
}
private float evaluateAll(){
    return (float) 0.0;

}

public List<Competition> getOpenCompetitions(){
    return null;
}

private User User(User u) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
} 

}
```

La clase User

```
   package edu.uoc.dpoo;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


     /**
       *
       * @author Guillermo Rodriguez Barcelo
       */
public class User {

private String username;
private String password;
private String fullName;

private Platform platform;

private List<Message> inBox;
private List<Message> outBox;

public User (String username, String password, String fullName) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.fullName = fullName;

    inBox = new ArrayList<Message>();
    outBox = new ArrayList<Message>();
}

User(String password, String fullname) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setFullName(String fullname) {
    this.fullName = fullname;
}


public boolean checkPasword(String password){
    return true;
}

public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return null;
}
public Organizer asOrganizer(){
    return null;
}
public Participant asParticipant(){
    return null;
}
public Message sendMessage(String to,String Subject,String message){
    return null;
}

public String toString () {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    return (boolean) obj;
}

    public List<Competition> myCompetitions(){
        return null;
    }


}
```

Por ultimo la clase donde hago el test y me falla el método

```
      User u2=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);
      assertNull(u2);
      assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);
```

La clase queda asi

```
package edu.uoc.dpoo;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project     Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import edu.uoc.dpoo.Organizer;  
import edu.uoc.dpoo.User;
import edu.uoc.dpoo.Platform;
import edu.uoc.dpoo.Participant;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

 /**
  *
  * @author xavie
  */
public class PR1_Ex2_1_Test {

private final String username1 = "username1";
private final String password1 = "password1";
private final String fullName1 = "Test User 1";

private final String username2 = "username2";
private final String password2 = "password2";
private final String fullName2 = "Test User 2";

public PR1_Ex2_1_Test() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
}

// Test create new user    
@Test
public void createUser() {        
    Platform platform = new Platform();

    // Check that no user is in the platform
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 0);

    // Register new user
    User u1=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);

    // User is not NULL
    assertNotNull(u1);

    // User full name is correct
    assertEquals(u1.getFullName(), fullName1);        

    // Check that only 1 user is in the platform (login does not created new user)
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);
}

 // Test create new user controls  
@Test
public void createUserControls() {        
    Platform platform = new Platform();

    // Check that no user is in the platform
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 0);

    // Register new user
    User u1=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);
    assertNotNull(u1);
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);

    // Try to register the same user again
    User u2=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);
    assertNull(u2);
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);

    // Register new user
    User u3=platform.registerUser(username2, password2, fullName2);
    assertNotNull(u3);
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 2);        
}
```

}

No entiendo por que me falla en los métodos

```
    assertNull(u2);
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno pues ya tengo la respuesta a mi pregunta la implementación de los métodos de la clase plattform para poder pasar el test queda asi:

```
   public User registerUser(String username ,String password,String fullname){

    User p = findUser(username);
    if (p == null) {
        p =  new User(username, password,fullname);
        users.add(p);
    }
    else {
        p=null;
    }

    return (User) p;
}



public User findUser (String username) {


           User user = null;

    for (User p : users) {
        if (username.equals(p.getUserName())) {
            user = p;//antes era = p
                            p= null;
            break;
        }
    }



    return user;
}


   public Integer getNumUsers(){
    Integer  size=users.size();

    return size  ;
}
```

Consegui sacarlo al final.